# header values appears more than once when converting json to csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv, object

I would like to know when converting json to csv using javascript, 
header appears more than once on every click.
Below is my code, on every click, header increases,
as shown in output below

```
 convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}

 exportCSV =() =>{
    const headers = ["Id", "Name", "City"];
    const items  = [
      [60, "xyz", "TH"],
      [62, "abc", "MY"],
      [61, "xxx", "IN"]
    ];
    const fileTitle = this.props.title;
    if (headers) {
        items.unshift(headers);
    }
    // Convert Object to JSON
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
    console.log(jsonObject);
    var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);
    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Output in csv like below,
on every click, header count increases

```
Id, Name, City
Id, Name, City
60, "xyz", "TH"
62, "abc", "MY"
61, "xxx", "IN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below simplified code for converting JSON to CSV (tried and tested in my application):

```js
var jsonData = {
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value"
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary"
    },
  ]
}
var JSONToCSVConvertor = function(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {

        let arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData.colors) : JSONData.colors;
        let CSV = '';
        //This condition will generate the Label/Header
        if (ShowLabel) {
            let row = "";
            //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
            for (let index in arrData[0]) {
                //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
                row += index + ',';
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);
            //append Label row with line break
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        //1st loop is to extract each row
        for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            let row = "";
            //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
            for (let index in arrData[i]) {
                row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
            }
            row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
            //add a line break after each row
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        if (CSV == '') {
            return;
        }
        return CSV;
    }
console.log(JSONToCSVConvertor(jsonData, 'test', true));
```